# Geocoder not returning results

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

This is my first JavaScript I have tried to put together but I am not having a lot of luck.

This is what the script should do: Geocode an address either by clicking on an autosuggested location or by clicking search button if we do not have the result already from clicking autosuggestion. Then submit the form.

I am not having much luck, it seems I have mucked up my bracketing on the script because no matter what I do it complains about exceptions.

This is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/31/):

```
geocode();

// SET COOKIE FOR TESTING PURPOSES   
    $.cookie("country", "US");

    // GEOCODE FUNCTION
    function geocode() {

        var coded = false;
        var input = document.getElementById('loc');
        var options = {
            types: ['geocode']
        };
        var country_code = $.cookie('country');
        if (country_code) {
            options.componentRestrictions = {
                'country': country_code
            };
        }
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        processLocation();
        });

// ON SUBMIT - WORK OUT IF WE ALREADY HAVE THE RESULTS FROM AUTOCOMPLETE FUNCTION
        $('#searchform').on('submit', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             if(coded = false;) {
                processLocation();
             } 
             else {
                $('#searchform').submit();
             }
        });

// CHECK TO SEE IF INPUT HAS CHANGED SINCE BEING GEOCODED
// IF "CODED" VAR IS FALSE THEN WE WILL GEOCODE WHEN SEARCH BUTTON HIT         
        $("#loc").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
             var coded = false; 
        });

    };  

// GEOCODE THE LOCATION
    function processLocation(){

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById('loc').value;
            $('#searchform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            },
                             
// RESULTS - STORE COORDINATES IN FIELDS OR ERROR IF NOT SUCCESSFUL
            function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var coded = true;
                    $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                    $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                } else {
                    var coded = false;
                    $('#searchform input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
                    alert("We couldn't find this location")
                }

            });
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

PS: Because this is my first script, I am happy to receive feedback if I have made any poor choices in the design of it. I really want to make my first script as cleanly coded as possible.

Comment: Consider closing this question under the following official reason: "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an syntax error

```
if(coded = false;) {
```

should be

```
if(coded == false) {
```

Checking the console would have told you such a thing and also the place WHERE the error occured.... Here's your fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sR4GR/33/)